# Is there a limit to the number of Claims you can have in Blazor server?

Tags: asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, claims

For Blazor (server side) using the ASP.NET Identity library, is there a limit to the number of claims you can have/use?

Is it putting all the claims in a cookie and/or passing them across in every request/response? If so, that’ll max out. But I would hope that for Blazor server that all stays in the server and so we don’t hit that limitation. So, exactly what/where are the limits for claims in Blazor server?